# Revoke only delete from user with all privileges on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

I have a user with all privileges for a specific DB in MySQL 8:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.* TO `foo`@`localhost`
```

I can check the grants with `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'foo'@'localhost';` and I get:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@localhost                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `foo`@`localhost`                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydatabase`.* TO `foo`@`localhost` |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I need to remove the DELETE grant on a specific table, so I've tried with:

```sql
REVOKE DELETE ON `mydatabase`.`mytable` FROM 'foo'@'localhost';
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1147 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'foo' on host 'localhost' on table 'mytable'
```

How can I remove the delete grant? I have to add all grants one by one (which ones are they?) and then remove the delete grant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GRANT` adds according row into privileges table.

`REVOKE` deletes the row with specified privilege from this table, not add another row with removing the privilege. So you can revoke only those privilege which is present in a table. Precisely.

You may:

1. Add separate privileges list with all privileges included into ALL PRIVILEGES except DELETE privilege on the database level
2. Add DELETE privilege on all tables except `mytable`
3. Remove ALL PRIVILEGES privilege

This is too complex. But correct.

---

Alternatively you may simplify the solution, do not use privileges system (of course this is not good practice), and forbid the deletion on the programming level using according trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER forbid_delete_for_user
BEFORE DELETE 
ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF LOCATE(USER(), 'foo@localhost,bar@localhost') THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Deletion from 'mytable' not allowed for current user.';
    END IF;
END
```

But you must remember that cascaded foreign key actions **do not activate triggers**. So the user can find the way for to delete the rows from this table nevertheless.